# What is the difference of SelectList and Projection in Nhibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

As the title says.

(To me it looks like `SelectList` is a way to create projections without using the `Projections` method.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say that full explanation is in the doc:

> QueryOver allows arbitrary IProjection to be added (allowing private
>   properties to be projected). The Projections factory class also has
>   overloads to allow Lambda Expressions to be used:
>
> ```
> IList selection =
>     session.QueryOver<Cat>()
>         .Select(Projections.ProjectionList()
>             .Add(Projections.Property<Cat>(c => c.Name))
>             .Add(Projections.Avg<Cat>(c => c.Age)))
>         .List<object[]>();
> ```
>
> In addition there is an inline syntax for creating projection lists
>   that does not require the explicit class qualification:
>
> ```
> IList selection =
>     session.QueryOver<Cat>()
>         .SelectList(list => list
>             .Select(c => c.Name)
>             .SelectAvg(c => c.Age))
>         .List<object[]>();
> ```

see [Check 16.6. Projections](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover-projections)